# How to delete a row from CSV in ruby with Table.delete_if()

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm reading in a csv file

```
require 'csv'

recipients = CSV.read('recipients.csv', headers: true)

found = []
if User.find_by(email: recipients['email'])
  found << recipients['email']
end

table = CSV.table('recipients.csv')

table.delete_if do |t|
  found.each { |f| t['email'] == f['email']}
end


CSV.open('/tmp/users.csv', 'wb') do |w|
  w << found.to_csv
end
```

The following line: `found.each { |f| t['email'] == f['email']}`
results in a

`TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
from lib/scripts/foo.rb:13:in`[]'`

It's obvious I don't grok how to use `delete_if` and how to resolve the type mismatch in this case. 
So, help is very much appreciated.

Comment: could you please post little more of the error log?

Comment: That is the error log. It's a type mismatch. The question is, why. And how to do the proper comparison.

Answer (score 0):

in line number `13`

```
  found.each { |f| t['email'] == f['email']}
```

`f` is an instance of `Array` and your are trying to pass a `String` as an index, so this might have occurred.

Explanation

```
 > a=[]
 => [] 
2.2.1 :015 > a['email']
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
    from (irb):15:in `[]'
```

---

```
 > a=['email', 'ram']
 => ["email", "ram"] 
2.2.1 :018 > a['email']
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
    from (irb):18:in `[]'
```